# big background without scrolls

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that has a wider background picture than the content area. I have made a 970px wrapper where the content is. And in the body I have a background image but I need to have another background image above the body background image so I have made class bgimg. So basically the markup is like this:

```
<body>
<bgimg>
<wrapper>
<content>
</content>
</wrapper>
</bgimg>
</body>
```

But the bgimg is about 1050px wide and thus it shows scrollbars when user's browser is 1024x768. Is there way of getting rid of the scrollbars? I mean I want to have have scrollbars if the user's browser is narrower than the 970x wrapper of course. So can I put something like overflow hidden for bgimg class?

Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS property for bgimg should do the trick:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css properties

```
body{overflow:hidden}
```